IRF540 MOSFET overheating when used with IRS2104 driver as class D amplifier

Source:
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRS2104-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567633f727a1
I'm trying to drive a Powerhap 1919 haptic actuator (which I have represented as the rightmost capacitor) with a class D stage, I have included the powerhap as a part of a pi LC filter. The trouble is even switching a moderate square wave of 15 kHz through the IN pin causes massive it to pull an amp of current from the MOSFET supply, it overheats the FET. There is no heating or power draw when no load is connected. The current draw just keeps increasing with frequency. I intend to go to much higher frequencies but I tried to send a sinewave as PWM switched at 30 kHz into IN and it's pulling way too much current. What's going on?

Is there a reason you are trying to drive the actuator with 15kHz (or higher)? These are made to be driven with a low frequency and the datasheet for the Powerhap 1919 limits the frequency to 500Hz with higher voltage square waves.

Get rid or significantly reduce the 2.5 μF capacitor. It will draw massive levels of near-instantaneous current on each switching cycle. A pi-filter is a bad idea under these circumstances.
It all boils down to \$i=C\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$.
For example if you switch 30 volts in 10 μs then the peak instantaneous current will be 7.5 amps. Do the math. If you switch in 1 μs then the peak current will be 75 amps.

I chose a pi filter because have an L filter with the actuator seemed to make the high frequency content pass through it which resulted in the actuator resonating, any other filter topology I should go for?

Also what do you mean by switching 30 volts in x uS? Regardless of the frequency of switching the instantaneous current should be the same right, since it's collapsing from 30 to 0 in the same time regardless of frequency

You must avoid resonating your actuator for sure so, that means choosing the series inductor to produce a resonant frequency that is a lot lower than the switching frequency. But, that resonant frequency also needs to be significantly higher than the sinewave frequency (the baseband signal).

Your supply is 30 volts and, the rising/falling edges will be in the microsecond or maybe sub-microsecond range. I just used two examples of risetimes; one at 10 us and, the other at 1 us @Vrisk
